# Rails pathname missing in environment.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, diaspora

When I'm trying to install Diaspora* and after my rake db:setup I get the following error when I try open it from the browser:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Pathname
/Users/myself/diaspora/config/environment.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
```

the line 15 is the first after the comment:

```
# Load the rails application
require Pathname.new(__FILE__).dirname.expand_path.join('application')
require Rails.root.join("lib", "exceptions")
```

I'm also using Pow.

Comment: Try adding `require 'pathname'` at the top of your `environment.rb`.  It's a core Ruby library and all versions since at least 1.8 will have it, assuming your Ruby is correctly installed.

Comment: I'll move this to the answer section for future searchers, then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `require 'pathname'` at the top of `environment.rb` to make this core Ruby library available.